# Can we sensibly universally quantify over a category? (Not a question about size issues.)

Tags: category-theory

You can get pretty far in mathematics without lambda abstraction. I guess this is because any formula of the form $\lambda^{x : X} f(x)=\lambda^{x : X}g(x)$ can always be replaced by the equivalent formula $\forall^{x : X}(f(x) = g(x)),$ which allows first-order logic to express equality of functions, despite the absence of lambda abstraction.

Now suppose $S$ and $C$ are posets, and that we're given order-preserving maps $f : S \rightarrow C$ and $u : C \rightarrow S$. Then the phrase "$f$ is left-adjoint to $u$" just means the following.

$$\forall^{s \in S, c \in C}(f(s) \leq c \leftrightarrow s \leq u(c)).$$

Reinterpreting "$\leftrightarrow$" as the equality relation on the Boolean domain, we can rewrite the above condition as an equality between two predicates:

$$\lambda^{s \in S, c \in C}(f(s) \leq c) =  \lambda^{s \in S, c \in C}(s \leq u(c)).$$

**I would like to use the above notations in order to reason about adjunctions between general categories.**

First, some notation: whenever $A$ and $B$ are parallel functors, I write $A \cong B$ for the set of all natural isomorphisms $A \Rightarrow B$.

Okay, now suppose $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are categories, and that we're given functors $F : \mathbf{S} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ and $U : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{S}$. Define $F \dashv U$ as the following set.

$$\mathbf{C}(F-,-) \cong \mathbf{S}(-,U-)$$

Then $F \dashv U$ can also be described as the following set.

$$\lambda^{S:\mathbf{S},C:\mathbf{C}}\mathbf{C}(FS,C)\cong \lambda^{S:\mathbf{S},C:\mathbf{C}}\mathbf{S}(S,UC)$$

This makes sense (I think) because $\mathbf{Cat}$ is a Cartesian closed category, and hence interprets lambda abstraction; I don't fully understand the details. Anyway, it would be nice if we could go one further step, and rewrite the above without lambda abstraction. That is, we'd like to say that the set $F \dashv U$ equals the following.

$$\forall^{S:\mathbf{S},C:\mathbf{C}}(\mathbf{C}(FS,C)\cong \mathbf{S}(S,UC))$$

Can we?

The following should suffice: given parallel functors $A$ and $B$ of type $\mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$, we'd like to be able to write the set $A \cong B$ using the notation $\forall^{X:\mathbf{C}}(A(X) \cong B(X)).$

> **Question.** Is it possible to make sense of universal quantification over a category? In particular, I'd like for it to hold that given parallel functors $A$ and $B$ of type $\mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$, the set $A \cong B$ can also be written $$\forall^{X:\mathbf{C}}(A(X) \cong B(X)).$$
>
> (I write $A \cong B$ for the set of all natural isomorphisms from $A$ to $B$).

Comment: It's far from the case that the foundational assumptions underlying the word "category" are universally agreed. If these are small categories, or categories small relative to a Grothendieck universe, then obviously everything can be done that can be done with sets. Do you know what foundational system you want to be in?

Comment: @KevinCarlson, I think you're accidentally identifying universal quantification over a category with universal quantification over the objects of that category. There's no reason why $\forall^{X:\mathbf{C}}$ necessarily has to be identified with $\forall^{X:\mathrm{Obj}\,\mathbf{C}}$. In any event, there's really nothing in the question that is sensitively dependent on size issues. If you want to work in a particular foundational system, feel free to work in Tarski-Grothendieck set theory.

Comment: This seems to be a question of language. You can invent whatever system of notation you like – it's better that it be self-consistent, but people don't usually bother to check that.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I'd **much** prefer the notation to have a proper semantics. "Pure" notation is weird and scary to me :) perhaps because it reminds me too much of "equations" like $ds^2 = dx^2+dy^2$ whose meaning was never properly explained haha

Comment: Semantics are not important until you have a deductive system. If you don't have a deductive system, it's just notation which can't be manipulated, so you can write whatever you like.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I prefer to search for semantics first, since then we have a way of deciding which inference rules can be expected to hold.

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer this question. Are you aware that you're talking about an aspect of the [Curry-Howard correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), the part relating universal quantification and dependent products?

Comment: @tcamps, tbh, the correspondence has never truly made sense to me. For example, it says that $\wedge$ corresponds to $\times$, which seems to make no sense because $\wedge$ is idempotent but $\times$ is not. Sure, they're defined by essentially the same universal property, but to me, $\times$ is strictly a generalization. In any event, feel free to make use the correspondence if it helps you answer the question, and I'll try to understand whatever I can.

Comment: @tcamps, I do see that there is *some* connection, namely that the statement $\forall^{x:X}(f(x)=g(x) : T(x))$ is equivalent to $\lambda^{x:X} f(x) = \lambda^{x:X}g(x) : \Pi^{x:X}T(x).$ Please comment if my notation is unclear. So dependent products certainly arise in a very natural way in connection with universal quantification. But to say that they're "essentially the same" seems completely wrong to me.